# javascript list containing object ordering according to a key

Tags: javascript

I want to order a javascript list containing object according to a key,

`var a = [{order: 1, item: 'shoes'}, {order: 3, item: 'jeans'}, {order: 2, item: 'shirt'}, {order: 1, item: 'coat'}]`

Here I want to order according to `order` from `lower` to `upper`  like:

`var b = a.filter(data => data.order)` // have some check here

How can I do that ?

Comment: use `Array#sort` method

Comment: `a.sort((a,b) => a.order - b.order)` works in ES6 I think

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

you need to sort by the property so you can use a functional style to curry the key, and return a function that `Array.prototype.sort` can use.

```js
var clothes = [
  { order: 1, item: 'shoes' }, 
  { order: 3, item: 'jeans' }, 
  { order: 2, item: 'shirt' }, 
  { order: 1, item: 'coat' }
]

const sortBy = key => (a, b) => a[key] - b[key]

console.log(
  clothes.sort(sortBy('order'))
)
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using `lodash`, you can do ([docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#sortBy))

```
_.sortBy(list, el => el.order);
```

If you are not (and I believe you should), you can take a look at their source code for hints ;)